# unable to find express on docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When i run my docker image i receive an error stating that it cannot find this module. But when I test my server outside of docker I do not see this error. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? I also have a dockerignore file that only has node_modules within.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /server
RUN npm install

COPY . /server

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "node", "/server/server.js" ]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=FoodCore
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Guy123su
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=FoodCore
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=Guy123su
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

[image: folder structure]

Comment: You need to `COPY package.json package.lock ./` before you can `RUN npm install`.

Comment: @DavidMaze i pasted that line under ```COPY . /server``` and moved ```RUN npm install``` below that line but that gives me an error when i build the image, unable to copy. Doesnt ```COPY . /server``` copy everything within that directory into the /server? so wouldnt package.json and package.lock already be in there since its not complaining about my other modules but just express??

Comment: What `WORKDIR` are you in when you `RUN npm install`?  (I think in the base `node` image you'll be in `/`, but you copy everything into `/server`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze So somehow it worked when i assed ```WORKDIR /server```. I didnt specify it, so im not sure how that had an impact.